# How do I subclass AVPlayer?

Tags: ios, design-patterns, avplayer, subclassing

I'm working to subclass `AVPlayer` so that I can create a method that `skipsBackwards` in a queue of music. I want to build a fully functional music player that uses music from the users iPod. So that means `AVAudioPlayer` is out as well as `MPMusicPlayerController`. Also Core Audio scares me so I'm hoping to steer clear of that for now.

I've considered using categories to extend the `AVPlayer` class but I need my subclass to have a class variable to store a `MPMediaItemCollection` so I figure it makes most sense to subclass rather that add a category.

Here's my exception

![enter image description here][1]

Here's my appDelegate code where I setup the `AVPlayer` that is subclassed as `SWPlayer`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
#import "SWPlayer.h"


@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;   
@property (nonatomic,retain)SWPlayer *bookPlayer;

@end

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    // Setup AudioSession
    NSError *sessionError = nil;
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate:self];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&sessionError];

    // Allow the audio to mix with other apps (necessary for background sound)
    UInt32 doChangeDefaultRoute = 1;
    AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers, sizeof(doChangeDefaultRoute), &doChangeDefaultRoute);

    //Grab some Songs to Test with
    MPMediaQuery *query = [MPMediaQuery songsQuery];
    NSArray *collection = [query items];

    //Setup bookPLayer to Test
    MPMediaItem *item = [collection objectAtIndex:5];
    NSLog(@"%@",[item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle]);
    NSURL *url = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
    self.bookPlayer = [[SWPlayer alloc]initWithURL:url];
    [bookPlayer play];

    [bookPlayer skipForwards];

    return YES;
}
```

Here is my very basic subclass...

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

@interface SWPlayer : AVPlayer

@property(nonatomic,retain)MPMediaItemCollection *mediaItemCollection;

-(void)skipForwards;
-(void)skipBackwards;

@end

#import "SWPlayer.h"

@implementation SWPlayer

@synthesize mediaItemCollection;

-(void)skipForwards{
    NSLog(@"SWPlayer called skipForward method");
}

-(void)skipBackwards{
    NSLog(@"SWPlayer called skipBackward method");

}

@end
```

The music plays using my subclass of `AVPlayer`. The issue is that as soon as I call the `skipForward` method of `SWPlayer` I get an unrecognized selector error and the app crashes. What I am missing here?

Comment: Regarding this very old question.  Just use **AVQueuePlayer**, that's it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `playerWithURL` method you are calling is owned by `AVPlayer` and will always return an `AVPlayer`, even when subclassed, unless you override it.  Try creating it with:

```
self.bookPlayer = [[SWPlayer alloc] initWithURL:url];
```

Comment: np, and thanks for reformatting the question so that other people can easily search it!

Comment: Reformatting is fine but it took me a while to notice that Peter refers to 'playerWithURL' - removing this from the original post makes it very hard to see where the problem WAS.